# What is the right translation for grade in the context of a course

Tags: word-choice, translation, word-requests

I want to know how to translate the word grade in sentences like

> what is the passing grade for this course?

or

> Where are the final grades posted?

I found some options in the dictionary like 採点{さいてん}, 級別{きゅうべつ} and 等級{とうきゅう}. But the dictionary doesn't give me enough context to decide if any of those is correct.

Are those translations o.k.? Should I use a different expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you are looking for is 成績{せいせき}. In general, it means "result", but is commonly used to mean "grade":

> 英語でいい成績を取った
>   I got a good grade in English.

Comment: passing grade って「合格点」かもね・・・